# Use URL instead of hostname with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, url, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am  using WinSCP to upload a file to an FTP host. But I only had `ftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx` path, not hostname like `ftp.example.com`.
Can I use `ftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx` for hostname?

My code is based on

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

// Configure proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "proxy");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload file
    string localFilePath = @"C:\path\file.txt";
    string pathUpload = "/file.txt";
    session.PutFiles(localFilePath, pathUpload).Check();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx` URL specify that you want to connect with FTP protocol to `xxx.xx.xx.xx` host.

That's what you do in WinSCP .NET assembly by setting [`SessionOptions.Protocol`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#protocol) and [`SessionOptions.HostName`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#hostname):

```
var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "xxx.xx.xx.xx",
    ...
};
```

---

Or you can use [`SessionOptions.ParseUrl`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_parseurl):

```
var sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.ParseUrl("ftp://xxx.xx.xx.xx");
...
```